# How would you call specific CSS stylesheet in a React component on a specific site?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I'm working on a platform built on React and that platform already has global CSS that is already set up for all clients a certain way.

A subset of affiliates under a common group name want a new sticky ad component that has to change the CSS a bit so the footer does not get covered up.

So normally, I'd check what our global variable value is, window.client.group, and if it's the certain group, add css or css stylesheet through javascript in an affiliate js file (our old generic platform).

The new CSS needed is:

```
  @media (max-width:767px){
    #ad201 {width:100%;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;z-
index:99999;margin:0;border:1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);background-
color:#fff;margin: 0 !important;}
    .Footer .container {padding-bottom:50px;}
  }
```

In React though, what's the best and most proper way to do this? 
As you can see it's complicated by needing to be in with a media query.

I have a start using group and matchMedia, but what's the best way to bring in the CSS? a whole stylesheet? (stickyAd.css? some other way? and tips on how to do it?)

```
const group = (window.client.group).toLowerCase();
console.log(group);

const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");

if ((mq.matches) && (group === 'premiere')) {
  // bring in the new css
} else {
  // do nothing
}
```

Thanks for the advice !

Comment: You can check this out: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components or just google for "javascript dynamically add css.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just declare a new class somewhere in your CSS, which will add the required rules when added to your detected objects? Media queries can be declared inside class declarations.

Comment: thanks @Hardy, will check it out.

Comment: @philraj, So add this css I need to a new class, but then call it from the ads component and footer component if it's the smaller screen size and premiere? I was hoping to drop code down in one component instead of multiple places, but this might work out the way i need. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @nyhunter77 Please see the answer I posted for more info -- it depends on how your ads are being inserted. Please comment on the answer with relevant info if needed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much control you have over the `ad201` and `Footer`.

I'm assuming Footer is a component you've created in React. In that case, you could add a class like `premiere-footer-fix` (you can probably think of a better name) to components being rendered when you detect your group:

```js
render() {
  const group = (window.client.group).toLowerCase();

  return (
    <Footer className={group === 'premiere' ? 'premiere-footer-fix' : ''}/>
  )
}
```

or if you import the very handy `classnames` package,

```js
import classNames from 'classnames';

// ...

render() {
  const group = (window.client.group).toLowerCase();
  const classes = classNames({
    'premiere-footer-fix': group === 'premiere'
  });

  return (
    <Footer className={classes}/>
  )
}
```

Then wherever you declare CSS for the Footer, you just add something like:

```css
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .Footer.premiere-footer-fix .container {
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
}
```

As for your ad, you'd have to provide more info about how it's being inserted into the page since it's not clear how much control you have over the element. But I would add `premiere` to your ad's `classList` and find a place to insert this bit of CSS:

```js
@media (max-width:767px) {
  #ad201.premiere {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Took a while to get back here but thanks for the advice! I ended up deciding to use classnames and it made it easy. We use props from JSON to enable and disable features with defaults set in the components. I added a classname that would activate should the ad have an adhesion prop and footer move should a prop be set. It's great because we can use the footer prop for other sticky ads from 3rd parties as well. Just awesome!

Comment: Glad you got everything sorted out. :-)